# javafx - table view mouse event not catched

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent

I have a TableView in my fxml. Within the controller this table is mapped with the @FXML annotation.

```
@FXML
TableView<BankMovement> table;
```

I also set, in fxml document, for table element

```
onMouseReleased = "#handleRowSelect"
```

finally always in the controller I have the following method

```
@FXML
private void handleRowSelect(MouseEvent event){
    Document row = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if (row == null) return;
    if(row != temp){
        temp = row;
        lastClickTime = new Date();
    } else if(row == temp) {
        Date now = new Date();
        long diff = now.getTime() - lastClickTime.getTime();
        if (diff < 300){ 
            System.out.println("Edit dialog");
            System.out.print(row.getDescription());
        } else {
            lastClickTime = new Date();
            System.out.print(row.getFile());

        }
    }
}
```

here instead is where to bind the data to table

```
@Override
public void initializeTable() {
    table.setItems(subList());
    colId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("idDocument"));
    colIdCategory.setCellValueFactory(d -> new SimpleStringProperty(d.getValue().getCategory().getName()));
    colIdCategoryChild.setCellValueFactory(d -> new SimpleStringProperty(d.getValue().getCategoryChild().getName()));
    colIdDocument.setCellFactory(getFileCellFactory());
    colIdDocument.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("file"));
    colIdDescription.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("description"));
    colIdDate.setCellValueFactory(d -> new SimpleStringProperty(Utils.localTimeToItalianDate(d.getValue().getDocumentDate())));
}
```

Even if I click on the table I never enter the handleRowSelect method.

I have the impression that when I click on the row the click on the cell is managed and not on the row. As if the event were not propagated.

This is fxml

```
<AnchorPane minWidth="-Infinity"  prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1510.0" styleClass="background-white" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MyController">
    <children>
        <VBox prefHeight="886.0" prefWidth="1465.0" style="-fx-min-width: 100%;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="330.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
            <children>
                <TitledPane animated="false" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="880.0" prefWidth="1465.0" text="%app.pane.document">
                    <content>
                        <VBox minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="815.0" prefWidth="1474.0">
                            <children>
                                <TableView onMouseReleased="#handleRowSelect" fx:id="table" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="746.0" prefWidth="1450.0">
                                    .......
                                    <padding>
                                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                    </padding>
                                </TableView>
                                <Pagination fx:id="pagination" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="1450.0" />
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Please include your actual FXML that is relevant. For one, you don't want a space between `#` and the method name.

Comment: Instead of calculating the time between clicks yourself, use the [getClickCount()](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount%28%29) method to determine whether the user has double-clicked.

Comment: @xtratic It's copy and past error. I added fxml.

Comment: @VGR It is irrelevant how I handle the double click. I don't go into the method. I checked with debugging.

Comment: @ciro Perhaps the controller is not actually being linked to this FXML? I see `fx:controller="MyController"` in your FXML file but maybe that's not actually being found.

Comment: Controller is correct. All works fine except table mouse events

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem? I'm having trouble reproducing the issue—the `MouseEvent` bubbles up to the `TableView` for me. Note I was using JavaFX 13.

Comment: I changed event and now it works. The event is onMouseClicked

Comment: Not sure if this has changes between versions or if I'm just not trying out the correct control (not in the mood of setting up a `TableView` right now), but iirc in the past there were some event handlers in the control that did indeed consume events preventing them from propagating to the control itself. To catch events like these, you need to use event filters instead of event handlers which unfortunately cannot be added from fxml. Try `table.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, this::handleRowSelect);` in the `initialize` method.